# Thinkpad X201i crashes and restarts when idle, when doing disk IO, when doing CPU intensive IDE debugging

Tags: crash, thinkpad

The X201i is experiencing sudden restarts randomly.

It is running Lubuntu `16.04`.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The distribution is up to date as of today and it still experiences the issue.

This happens regardless if the system is idle, the system is running on battery, or the system is running on power.

I tried a few things.

The first one was configuring the Linux OS so that it does NOT override the BIOS configuration:
In the `/etc/default/grub` file I added the property `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` at the end of the line containing the "quiet splash" value like 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"`.
At the same time I configured the BIOS so that the CPU was running at its maximum power, avoiding energy savings modes.
It seemed to help a bit in that it felt like it crashed less often, a few times during the day instead of every half hour.

Another thing I did is I tried to lower the screen refresh frequency from 60 to 50 but that did nothing to improve the situation.

One last thing I did was turn off the swap with the `sudo swapoff -a` command but this too did nothing to improve things.

It is really happening at random times, sometimes I'm not even by the machine. I can leave it on running and if when I come back a few hours later most likely it will have restarted.

Then I noticed something that makes it crash and restart consistently: if I try to copy lots of files from my hard drive to an external usb drive with the `cp -fr work/* /media/.../work` command, or if I try to run the following command `dosfsck -a /dev/sdb1` to fix the external hard drive, it also crashes and restart. This made me think the issue is related to the hard drive operations.

I ran a long test using the `sudo smartctl -H -t long /dev/sda1` command and the results looked fine:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda1
[sudo] Mot de passe de stephane : 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-83-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MK..61GSY[N]
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK2561GSY
Serial Number:    61SHTKL8T
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 35180a4ef
Firmware Version: MC001D
User Capacity:    250 059 350 016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jul  5 11:12:09 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  67) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 128
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1154
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  9 Power_On_Minutes        0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       4591h+59m
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1278
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       151
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       114
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       23173
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 5/48)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26466059
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       71774442
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       492201
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7380666319
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6705692631
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4591         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1102         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1102         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1102         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1101         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I've also run another long test using the `sudo smartctl -H -t long /dev/sda6` command and its result was:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda6
[sudo] Mot de passe de stephane : 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-83-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MK..61GSY[N]
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK2561GSY
Serial Number:    61SHTKL8T
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 35180a4ef
Firmware Version: MC001D
User Capacity:    250 059 350 016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jul  5 12:44:57 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  67) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 128
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1168
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  9 Power_On_Minutes        0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       4593h+30m
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1279
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       151
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       115
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       23179
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 5/48)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26786987
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       71797822
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       492216
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7381212201
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6707899566
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4593         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4591         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1102         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1102         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1102         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1101         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

UPDATE: I just noticed that doing debbuging under Eclipse consistently causes the crash and restart.

UPDATE: I had an idea this morning. I thought, what if I keep restarting the computer all day without waiting for the issue to occur ? Will I then see the issue occur today ? And so I did. I kept restarting the computer every now and then, quite often I must admit. I would work a bit, and then restart it. And, at the end of the day, I can say, it never crashed. That leads me to think there is something at play with entropy or garbage collection here.

Comment: First, who installed Linux? Then, when was this issue first noticed? On getting the machine? On installing Linux? After an update? After installing software or hardware? BTW, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop might be more stable -- check from a thumb drive.

Comment: I did the Linux installation. It was the 50th time I had installed an Ubuntu distribution. A walk in the park. I did my custom partitioning as usual. This issue was first noticed not too long after (say 2 weeks) I had swapped the 2 sticks of 8Gb RAM total for 2 sticks of 16G RAM total. But I had the machine for a very short time before that (say a month). My Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.

Comment: Your original statement was "Lubuntu"... which is the distro on this machine?

Comment: It is a Lubuntu distribution. The commands `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` mention Ubuntu though. But I'm positive it is a Lubuntu. The GUI menu has an item named `Logithèque Lubuntu`.

Comment: As mentioned above, try Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop -- a bit larger, perhaps, than Lubuntu, but it is more likely to have all needed drivers etc. If it doesn't crash from a USB flash drive, it  might be worth considering.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I will give it a try then, cheers.

Comment: I downloaded `Ubuntu 16.04 ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` and run it live from a USB key drive installation. It ran smoothly all evening and all night with no crash at all. Now, I don't think it performed any disk IO. It still makes me want to install it though.

Comment: I could trigger the crash and restart issue on the live running `Ubuntu 16.04 ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` as well, by doing the same copy of a lot of files onto an external usb drive. Then I played with tools like `stress` and `stress-ng` and stressed the 4 cores of the CPU and nothing happened. Then, using the same tools I stressed the memory usage and it instantly crashed and restarted. I conclude my memory is faulty.

Comment: Running the `memtest86+` command consistently causes the crash and restart of the system.

Comment: You may refer to the documentation for the smartmontools, however the values reported by smartctl look OK to me. It seems to be quite an old drive (~4600 powered on hours), but the raw read error rate and the reassigned sector count are low (0 and 1 respectively). So IMHO there is no obviously disk issue.
FYI, sda1 and sda6 are most likely just two different partitions or "slices" of the same physical disk. That's why the two tests report such similar numbers. So it's sufficient to test the device "/dev/sda".

Comment: If the memory is reporting errors, it could (perhaps) be a thermal problem. Perhaps more likely on an older system ... Thinkpads usually have several temperature sensors, so it might be worth checking their values and also trying to clean out any dust e.g. from the fan, so that it can do its job properly. For example see also the [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thermal_sensors). Good luck!

Comment: I think the 2*8GB=16GB memory sticks I plugged into the machine might be a bit too fast for it. I'm thinking of buying a pair of 1096Mgh ones `Crucial kit 8Go DDR3 1066MHz`.

Comment: I have a big fan blowing air onto the computer, the keyboad is barely warm, and it still did the crash and restart figure. One thing to note, is that it has never done it twice in a row, there is always a time of at least half an hour, usually more like 2h, except when I play with the external usb drive as explained above.

Comment: I don't think heat is the issue here. If you saw my question update, you can see that restarting the machine often prevented any crash from occuring. And I used the machine all day, a warm day today in fact.

Comment: I got me a pair of 4Gb 1096Mgh sticks and installed them yesterday. Since then, there hasn't been a single crash, even when doing the operations that before crashed it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect a problem with the disk subsystem, one of the best things to do would be to install the smartmontools package and then run, for example:

```
smartctl -H /dev/sda
```

(specifying sda or whatever device name(s) your Linux distribution is using.)

The "H" flag performs a health check on the specified disk. There are a lot of other options, check the manual pages and package documentation.

Of course you should also check the messages from the Linux system itself e.g. via dmesg and by looking through the log files in (typically) /var/log.

Comment: I did install the `smartmontools` utility now and rant the check on my hard drive with `sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda1` and `sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda6` for the root and home partitions, and both showed a `PASSED` result. I have now started some long test `sudo smartctl -H -t long /dev/sda1` and will have some results in about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Either the X201i doesn't handle 16 GB of memory or doesn't handle memory faster than 1096Mgh. The 2 * 4 GB memory sticks I installed yesterday seem to be a solution. There hasn't been a single crash since. Even when doing the operations that before crashed it consistently.